# Create multiple columns by pivoting even when pivoted value doesn't exist

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pivot, multiple-columns, pyspark-pandas

I have a PySpark `df`:

| Store_ID | Category | ID | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 123 | 23 |
| 2 | A | 123 | 45 |
| 1 | A | 234 | 67 |
| 1 | B | 567 | 78 |
| 2 | B | 567 | 34 |
| 3 | D | 789 | 12 |
| 1 | A | 890 | 12 |

Expected:

| Store_ID | A_ID | B_ID | C_ID | D_ID | Sales_A | Sales_B | Sales_C | Sales_D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 102 | 78 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 45 | 34 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 12 |

I am able to transform this way using SQL (created a temp view):

```
SELECT Store_Id,
       SUM(IF(Category='A',Sales,0)) AS Sales_A,
       SUM(IF(Category='B',Sales,0)) AS Sales_B,
       SUM(IF(Category='C',Sales,0)) AS Sales_C,
       SUM(IF(Category='D',Sales,0)) AS Sales_D,
       COUNT(DISTINCT NULLIF(IF(Category='A',ID,0),0)) AS A_ID,
       COUNT(DISTINCT NULLIF(IF(Category='B',ID,0),0)) AS B_ID,
       COUNT(DISTINCT NULLIF(IF(Category='C',ID,0),0)) AS C_ID,
       COUNT(DISTINCT NULLIF(IF(Category='D',ID,0),0)) AS D_ID
FROM df
GROUP BY Store_Id;
```

How do we achieve the same in PySpark using native functions as its much faster?

Comment: what you need is `pivot()`. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72787341/8279585) SO Q's answer for details

Comment: possible duplicate of [aggregate pyspark dataframe and create multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72787341/8279585)

Comment: can you answer the question? That is a differnt objective and im stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This operation is called pivoting.

- a couple of aggregations, since you need both, count of ID and sum of Sales
- `alias` for aggregations, for changing column names
- providing values in pivot, for cases where you want numbers for Category C, but C doesn't exist. Providing values boosts performance too.

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 'A', 123, 23),
     (2, 'A', 123, 45),
     (1, 'A', 234, 67),
     (1, 'B', 567, 78),
     (2, 'B', 567, 34),
     (3, 'D', 789, 12),
     (1, 'A', 890, 12)],
    ['Store_ID', 'Category', 'ID', 'Sales'])
```

Script:

```py
df = (df
    .groupBy('Store_ID')
    .pivot('Category', ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
    .agg(
        F.countDistinct('ID').alias('ID'),
        F.sum('Sales').alias('Sales'))
    .fillna(0))
df.show()
# +--------+----+-------+----+-------+----+-------+----+-------+
# |Store_ID|A_ID|A_Sales|B_ID|B_Sales|C_ID|C_Sales|D_ID|D_Sales|
# +--------+----+-------+----+-------+----+-------+----+-------+
# |       1|   3|    102|   1|     78|   0|      0|   0|      0|
# |       3|   0|      0|   0|      0|   0|      0|   1|     12|
# |       2|   1|     45|   1|     34|   0|      0|   0|      0|
# +--------+----+-------+----+-------+----+-------+----+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you . I really appreciate your response.  A small question here ..Will the `count `used give the distinct count of ID column or will it count everything?In case I want to count distinct Ids only what should I do?

Comment: I've updated the answer while you were testing. I've replaced `count` with `countDistinct`